# Predicate logic statements with one and multi parameters

Tags: logic, induction, proof-explanation, predicate-logic

I'm new to the Math stack exchange community so my apologies in advance in making mistakes for putting my question into non-fitting categories and such.

**Ultimate Question:** When are you supposed to use n-ary predicate statements for proving any sort of proof-based questions? (In my context, any of the three inductions) In case there may be any confusion due to many different theories and notation for predicate logic n-ary as in... i.e. P(x, y) or P(x, y, z) or n-ary P(x_0, x_1, ... , x_n-1)

**Sub-Question #1:** I thought about this question myself and came up with sub-question like what the difference is between the two following predicates and I was not able to find the answer what the difference is searched online however no really specific and detailed answer but here it is:

**Sub-Question #2:** Does every variable that is used in the predicate sentence need to be bounded by a quantifier?

Consider, the two following question:

1. Prove that for all natural numbers $n, k*n \ge n$ for any natural number $k \ge 2.$

I thought of two predicates and two separate claims that I have made for the above question as follows:

Define a set $S =\{s \in \mathbb {N}\}.$

Also, define set $Y = \{y \in \mathbb {N} \; | \; y\ge 2\}.$

**Predicate and Claim #1**

Define the predicate $P:S \rightarrow \{True, False\}$

and is defined as $P(n): "k*n \ge n"$

**Claim #1:** $ \forall \;  n\in S, P(n)$ holds.

**NOTE:** The bounded variable in the predicate would be $n$ and the free variable would be the $k$ because it is not bounded by some quantifier. So a natural question to ask is, do I have to/neccessary to bound the free variable $k$ in proving this question?

**Claim #2:** $ \forall \; n \in S , \forall \; k \in Y, P(n)$ holds.

**Predicate and Claim #2**

Define the predicate $P: (S \times S) \rightarrow \{True, False\}$

and is defined as $P(n, k): \; "k*n \ge n"$

**Claim:** $\forall n \in S, \; \forall k \in Y, \; P(n, k)$ holds.

**Sub-Question #3:** (I just thought of this question while writing this post...) If I have some arbitrary predicate statement (and ONLY THE predicate statement) $P(n)$, is the $n$ considered to be a free variable?

So out all the this attempts are any of them correct and if not can anyone provide with a proper rigorously defined predicate for the above question?
Also, it will be very appreciated if someone can point out what basic background I might lack in to have this problem and also suggest any sort of textbooks or any online material that can possibly help me strengthen my knowledge in this field! I personally find that defining a predicate is the basis of learning how to rigorously prove any mathematical or non-mathematical statements.

Thank you so much in advance! :)

**EDIT #1:** Thank you for both of your answers but I did not state explicitly what the question I had in my mind. (My apologies, it was quite late last night wasn't able to think very straight)

I want to ask what the difference between my Claim #1 and Claim #2 and the difference between both of the two predicates that I defined. From my perspective the only difference I can spot in the predicate is the very explicit view which is my first predicate is unary and second predicate is binary BUT do not understand what the mathematical difference is.

Comment: In claim #1 we have $k$ a constant term. Otherwise it is not well formed. In claim #2 $k$ is bounded because of the quantifier, so the claim is well formed predicate. For the statement $P(n)$, $n$ is free if and only if $n$ is not bounded to any quantifier, those terms are called *quantifier free*, and it is depends on the domain if this is well formed. Important note **free variable, $n$, doesn't not implies $n$ is not bounded**. For the ultimate question, n-ary is used if you have $n$ different *variables*, there may be how many constant terms in there, they may or may not be bounded or free

Comment: Thank you but I was not clear enough so if you can kindly read my edit of the post will be appreciated!

Comment: #1: $k$ is a constant in the language.  #2: $k$ is bounded variable. In Both cases $n$ is bounded variable. It is important to see that $k$ in $P$(I'm talking about #1) is not a free variable because unless you specific the language we are in. In which case $k$ is either a constant or a free variable

Comment: So the difference is that $k$ is a constant in #1 and $k$ is a bounded variable in #2, so what is the difference between the two and how and why would we treat them differently later on in the proof (of the question)? So what language are you talking about specifically to make the variable $K$ either a constant or a free variable in fact even bounded? From my knowledge, I think the variable $k$ would be bounded if it is **quantified** but not sure when a variable is a free variable or a constant... And what would be the difference between the free variable and a constant?

Comment: What did you also mean by "well-formed"? Also, then what would make the difference between my first unary predicate and the binary predicate? Sorry for so many questions... this is a concept I've been wondering and none of my professors at school are capable of answering these questions unfortunately.

Comment: in logic we work with formal languages, every language has rules, a statement inside of a language is well formed iff it withstand all of the rules. As for variables: variable, in loosely fashion, is a replacement for a string. Every variable "starts" *free* and changes accordingly: if quantifier got added to it it 'becomes' *bounded*, if the variable is outside of the language it 'becomes' *constant*, otherwise it will stay *free*. Now, because in your example(#1) we know that $k$ is not operator, and $P$ uses it but does not require it, we assume it is constant...

Comment: ... In the second case we have all of the variable being bounded, so we can look at it very literally: for all $n$ in $S$ we have that for all $k$ in $Y$ we have $P(n,k)$. Proving this is not hard using induction: for arbitrary $n$ we take the base case $k=2$ and get then show that if it holds for $k$ it holds for $k+1$(btw, induction is something we need to prove to exist, but idk what and where exactly in the material you are at now so I assume you can)

Comment: When you say "If the variable is outside of the language it becomes constant, otherwise it will stay free." what is the language that we are referring to? Is the $P(n)$ the language or the claim #1 the language? I would assume it would make more logical sense to think that the claim is the language... Because if the predicate $P(n)$ was the language you are referring to the variable $k$ is indeed in the language thus, making it **not a constant.** So $k$ will be free. I think you misunderstood with the difference in the cases I was referring to the first predicate but claim #1 and claim #2.

Comment: The only formal language I am aware of is in automata theory which refers to a set. Unforunately not in logic unless it's very similar. I was wondering also if there is any sort of PDF or book out there that you can possibly recommend to strengthen my knowledge on this topic of predicates will be appreciated! I have never seen a single textbook or any sort of article that actually goes on this level of discussion of a predicate in a proof I don't know why it's so neglected.

Comment: The confusion I gave you with the two cases as mentioned above essentially what I am asking is what the difference between $\forall n \in  S \; \forall k \in Y \; P(n)$ and $\forall n \in  S \; \forall k \in Y \; P(n, k)$.

Comment: the language we talk about (most of the time) in set theory is first (or second) order logic. You defined $P(n)$, this means that $P$ **has to be a term**, it means that we can use $P(n)$ without any specifics, so in this case saying $(\forall n\in S)(P(n))$ is a claim, so $k$ is a constant. But saying $P(n,k)$ gives as a term that for which $k$ is not a constant. So in #1 **k is a constant**. Basically, if you use a function (or predicate, or formula) it has to be able to stand alone, because in claim #1 you stated a claim it means that $P(n)$ can stand alone

Comment: Still unclear on this topic of question, ugh. Sorry, could you possibly state what the difference $ \forall n \in S \forall k \in Y P(n)$ and $\forall n \in S \forall k \in Y P(n, k)$? Is the first one illegal because there is no $k$ in the predicate $P(n)$? If it is legal then can I safely conclude that the $k$ is a bounded variable? If this is the case then there would be **no difference** between the two statements that I made.

Comment: the first one is $\forall n\in S\forall k\in Y(k'n\ge n)$, where $k'_{\text{constant}}\ne k$ and the second is $\forall n\in S\forall k\in Y(kn\ge n)$

Comment: You just completely lost me there why is $k'$ not equal to $k$? The $k$ is both bounded in both of the claims. I am not understanding any part of the answer you just gave me. Why are they denoted differently?

Comment: You can't have $P(n)$ using variables other than $n$, so the $k$ inside of $P$ is a constant, so I had to rename it to be different from the other $k$

Comment: So does that mean the $\forall n \in S \forall k \in Y P(n)$ this claim here the $\forall k \in Y$ have no affect on the claim itself? While the second claim does have an affect since $k$ is indeed a parameter of $P(n, k)$?

Comment: yes, exactly.       .

Comment: That clears it up a lot, thank you very much really really appreciate that, my final question and confirmation would be for the proof question (Prove that for all natural numbers n,k∗n≥n for any natural number k≥2.) the appropriate and correct predicate would be the one with binary predicate variables $P(n, k)$ then right? Since $P(n)$ itself would be just always referring to the $k$ just as a single constant. While the question is asking for not just a specific constant but for all $k \ge 2$.

Comment: Another question that it provokes me to ask if you kindly wouldn't mind answering is, since I do think that the claim $\forall n \in S \forall k \in Y \; P(n, k)$ holds is the **correct claim** to prove the above question... What would happen if I claim a statement without quantifying one of the variables $\forall n \in S \; P(n, k)$ then we know that $k$ is not bounded then would $k$ not being a bounded variable affect anything in my proof (suppose an inductive proof)? What changes in the proof for having a free variable and a bounded variable? i.e. having a bounded $k$ and a free variable k.

Comment: it depends on the universe of the language (sorry I return to language again but it is unavoidable), a lot of times it doesn't change anything if $Y=U_\text{niverse}$ then it doesn't matter, otherwise, it does

Comment: Could you specify on your answer? I'm not understand specifically what the matter is for preventing you to kindly answer the questions that was stated above? So does that mean (assuming that $Y = U$) then the two claims $\forall n \in S \forall k \in Y P(n, k)$ and $\forall n \in S P(n, k)$ has no difference?

Comment: Also, a further question in the predicate #1 and predicate #2 I want the $k$ value to be a constant anyways so what makes the "constants" so different? The difference I'm seeing between the two predicates is that the in the first predicate $P(n)$ the $k$ is a fixed constant where it cannot be changed where as $P(n, k)$ the $k$ is a constant where it can be changed? Correct me if I'm wrong thanks!

Comment: @Holo Whenever you have time if you can answer my question will be very much appreciated! Thanks, seems like you're the only person that I can rely on here. :(

Comment: It seems to me that the set $S$ is a singleton set whose one and only element is that $s \in \Bbb{N}$ which is to say that $s$ is an element of $\Bbb{N}$ or more intuitively that $s$ is a natural number.   Then there is a mapping $P$ from $S$ into the two element set $\{\hbox{true, false}\}$.  The way I understand this would be that $P(x)$ must be either true or false (not both).  But you have written $P(n)$: kn \geq n$.  So it seems that $P$ is being used in two different senses here:

Answer (score 1):

We have that :

> "for all natural numbers $n, k  n ≥ n$ for any natural number $k ≥ 2$"

is:

> > $\forall n \forall k \ (k \ge 2 \to kn \ge n)$.

Thus, both variables $n$ and $k$ are (universally) quantified.

We assume that the domain is $\mathbb N$ : thus we can omit the "specification" : $\in \mathbb N$.

If we want to set-up a typical inductive proof, we can consider the binary predicate $P(n,k) := kn \ge n$ and apply induction on $k$ :

*(i) Basis* : $k=2$.

We have that $2n = n+n \ge n$.

*(ii) Induction step* : assume that the property holds for $k \ge 2$ and prove for $k+1$.

If $k+1 \ge 2$ (and thus $k \ge 1$, ensuring that $kn \ne 0$), we have that $(k+1)n=kn+n \ge n+n \ge n$.

In conclusion, we have $P(n,2) \text{ and } \forall k (k \ge 2 \to (P(n,k) \to P(n,k+1)))$. Thus, we can apply induction to conclude with:

> $\forall k \ (k \ge 2 \to P(n,k))$.

But the result holds for $n$ whatever; thus we can generalize it to:

> $\forall n \ \forall k \ (k \ge 2 \to kn \ge n)$.

Comment: Thank you but I was not clear enough so if you can kindly read my edit of the post will be appreciated!

Comment: For your above set-up of the proof that you gave you would have to apply induction twice for $k$ and $n$ right?

Comment: @javacoder - Yes and no; both steps ultimately rely on the fact that $n+n \ge n$. In foraml arithmetic we usually define $m \ge n \text { iff } \exists k (m=n+k)$; if so, from $n+n=n+n$ we have imemdiately yields : $n + n \ge n$. But of course induction will work: $n+0 \ge n$ by axiom and so on.